# how to install gazebo from source in ROS fuerte?

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i need to update my gazebo version because the one that fuerte has don't works with the colission sensors...

Can anybody halp me?

EDIT.........

Well, i did what @lorenz say but when i run the new gazebo i obtain this error:

```
jose@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
... logging to /home/jose/.ros/log/db94fb8e-3a37-11e2-aee9-e0ca942b6aa6/roslaunch-ubuntu-6598.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:45513/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [6618]
/home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo: 16: /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo: /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzserver: not found
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 6618, exit code 127, cmd /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/jose/.ros/log/db94fb8e-3a37-11e2-aee9-e0ca942b6aa6/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/jose/.ros/log/db94fb8e-3a37-11e2-aee9-e0ca942b6aa6/gazebo-1*.log
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [6625]
/home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: línea 2: /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/bin/gzclient: No existe el archivo o el directorio
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 6625, exit code 127, cmd /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/jose/.ros/log/db94fb8e-3a37-11e2-aee9-e0ca942b6aa6/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/jose/.ros/log/db94fb8e-3a37-11e2-aee9-e0ca942b6aa6/gazebo_gui-2*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49397/how-to-install-gazebo-from-source-in-ros-fuerte?/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-29**:
The binary doesn't seem to be present. Are you sure you built it using rosmake?

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-29**:
no, i'm making it... Thank you!

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-29**:
i get this error:
-- BUILD ERRORS: These must be resolved before compiling.
--    Missing: Google Protobuf (libprotobuf-dev)
--    Missing: Google Protobuf Compiler Library (libprotoc-dev)
--    Missing: libtar
-- END BUILD ERRORS

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-29**:
The error tells you that it could not find some libraries. Just install them: `sudo apt-get install libprotoc-dev libtar-dev libprotobuf-dev libcegui-mk2-dev`

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-29**:
i have to do the rosmake again???

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-29**:
Sure. If the build failed you need to fix the problem and rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you'll have to check out the ROS stack for gazebo and put it into your ros workspace ([instructions for setting up a workspace](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays)):

```
rosws set --svn simulator_gazebo https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk
rosws update
```

Then just build the stack with rosmake:

```
rosmake simulator_gazebo
```

If I'm reading the Gazebo CMakeLists.txt file correctly, it will use the development version from mercurial by default.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-29**:
hello, i did what you say but how can i know which version of gazebo i have installed o where is installed this nwe version

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-29**:
The new version is installed right in the ros package. `roscd gazebo` will jump to the gazebo package that is used and `rospack find gazebo` will show you the path. Note that you might need to re-compile gazebo plugins if there were ABI changes in the dev version of gazebo.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-29**:
i run gazebo but is the same version in the cmakelist file i have this: rosbuild_make_distribution(1.6.16), and the problem with the contact sensors is not fixed

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-29**:
Sorry. I had a little mistake in my rosws command. Please edit the file $ROS_WORKSPACE/.rosinstall and fix the url of the gazebo repository. It should be the last line in that file. Then run `rosws update` and open a new terminal or re-source the setup.bash file in your overlay.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-30**:
hello, i have a question, can i install any gazebo version for my ros fuerte?, because the version that i installed yesterday don't works very well and is too heavy for my hardware especifications...

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-30**:
You can install whatever version you want. You just need to change the CMakeLists.txt file and the makefile that is used for downloading gazebo's source code manually.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-30**:
what version is the most estable??

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-30**:
That I don't know. For me the default ROS gazebo in fuerte always worked perfectly fine.

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-30**:
yes, but has problems with the contacsensor, thank you for everything...

**Comment by [Andrei Haidu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1419/andrei-haidu/) on 2012-12-04**:
after rosmake I get the following error:
Linking CXX shared library libgazebo_sdf_interface.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
And I have this library in usr/lib